# Need script to make scheduled 8 channel relay outputs

Tags: gpio, python, relay

This script fires my relays, but I don't know how to change duration and need it to fire daily to run pump and ozonator for an iso float tank.  I'm currently only using GPIO 9 and 10

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# init list with pin numbers

pinList = [10, 9]

# loop through pins and set mode and state to 'low'

for i in pinList:
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

# time to sleep between operations in the main loop

SleepTimeL = 2

# main loop

try:
  GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)
  print ("OZONE")
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.output(9, GPIO.LOW)
  print ("PUMP")
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.cleanup()
  print ("Good bye!")

# End program cleanly with keyboard
```

Comment: This is a question on how to program.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is a very good program, so flexible to scale up.  I would suggest the following changes.

1. To scale up from 2 relays to 8 relays, change the following first statement to second:

   pinList = [10, 9]

   pinList = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]

---

2. To change operation delay from two seconds to three seconds, say, change the following first statement to second.

   SleepTimeL = 2

   SleepTimeL = 3

---

3. To scale up two relay operations to eight, change the following 6 line segment to the for loop after.

   GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)

   print ("OZONE")

   time.sleep(SleepTimeL)

   GPIO.output(9, GPIO.LOW)

   print ("PUMP")

   time.sleep(SleepTimeL)

---

```
for pin in pintlist:

    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW) 

    print ("OZONE") 

    time.sleep(SleepTimeL)
```

---

There is 99% chance the my suggested changes create bugs. Don't worry.  Report your bugs as a comment below my answer.  Everybody would come to help.

---

Comment: @Gcprince, please report bugs here. Cheers.

Comment: @Gcprince, I would also suggest you to debug your nice little code in Rpi built in Thonny python IDE, which is very newbie friendly and helps to locate errors in its newbie friendly GUI (Graphics User Interface) console window, showing which line makes trouble, and leading you to that exact line where it is, and waits for you to correct it and immediately run it to retry your luck. It is so Pachinko like game fun!. Happy  programming.  Cheers.